# Problem concerning null safety in functions

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have this function called add which adds two numbers and returns the result in dart.

```dart
void main() {
  int step1Result = add(n1: 5, n2: 9);
  int step2Result = multiply(step1Result, 5);
  double finalResult = step2Result / 3;
  print(finalResult);
}

int add({int n1, int n2}){
  return n1 + n2;
}
```

but it keeps on throwing the error that `n1` and `n2` can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
I tried adding the `?` mark but the it threw another error saying

`The operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.`

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the declaration of your `add` function:
Here

```dart
int add({int n1, int n2}){
    // ...
}
```

Here you're declaring two *optional* parameters to the functions.
But `n1` and `n2` are `int` and not `int?`

To fix this issue, you can either transform your function to take `int?` types.
Or to add the `required` keyword to tell that the function will only work if both parameters will be given.

```dart
void main() {
    int step1Result = add(n1: 5, n2: 9);
    int step2Result = multiply(step1Result, 5);
    double finalResult = step2Result / 3;
    print(finalResult);
}

int add({required int n1,required int n2}){
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

You can learn more about null-safety syntax and principles on the official documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem